# What is camera update factory in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

`mMap.moveCamera()`

In the above code accepted parameter is `CameraUpdate` however in documents it is given as, we should use `CameraUpdateFactory` class to implement methods.

Why is it like that

Answer (score 0):

From the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory), CameraUpdateFactory class contains methods for creating CameraUpdate objects. So you should use the factory to create a CameraUpdate like this.

```
 //move and animate the camera
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(0.0,0.0)))
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11f), 2000, null)
```

Comment: Then what is the use of `CameraUpdate` if we are anyway going to use `CameraUpdateFactory`